# Is it possible to prepare an environment that the application will see as having more cores, the ones of other LAN hosts for distributed/parallel?

Tags: compiling, parallel-ssh

I have 4 PCs, they all are 8+ years old. I can connect them all thru LAN cable or WIFI.
I will run it from my desktop PC.

I was trying to read about `parallel` but there seems to have a lot of confusion (or it is just me?) about the word "parallel" (and its meaning: fork, child, distributed processing) and the application `parallel` (over ssh too) and I ended up with a huge lot more results to read about than what I expected on google...

Also, if such pseudo/virtual environment could let the application think there is not only 4 cores (local machine) but 12 cores (the total sum of cores over LAN), and just send whatever it is needed for these jobs (or threads) work remotely (but read/write data only from/to the local machine), I think the complexity to send specific requests to each host could be lowered to the end user/developer.
So the remote hosts would only use the processor and RAM, not their HDs for input/output.
And the application (or compiler) would detect this pseuso local/virtual machine as a different thing that has a lot of cores (and may be RAM too).

PS.: My initial question idea was: is it possible to let a compilation be processed in several machines in parallel?
But as I am trying to compile unreal engine that uses mono, I think it may not be exactly using `make` as expected right?
So I will thank also if you can point me to a way to accomplish my specific quest about compiling UE in several machines using linux. But the question subject remains as a transparent pseudo/virtual environment to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the way you're thinking anyway[1].  Programs have to be specially written to use multiple CPU cores across the network, usually involving linking to a message passing library like [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) or [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/) - these are typically used on HPC clusters, along with cluster management software like [slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager) or [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System).

You are in luck, though, because there is an existing program to do exactly what you want, use a bunch of machines on a network to compile software: [distcc](https://distcc.github.io/)

Extract from the debian package description:

```
Package: distcc
Version: 3.4+really3.3.5-3
Description-en: simple distributed compiler client and server
 distcc is a program to distribute compilation of C or C++ code across
 several machines on a network. distcc should always generate the same
 results as a local compile, is simple to install and use, and is often
 significantly faster than a local compile. distcc does not require all
 machines to share a filesystem, have synchronized clocks, or to have
 the same libraries or header files installed.
```

I have no idea whether `distcc` works for compiling Unreal Engine code or not - isn't that Windows only?

[1] not entirely true.  What you're talking about is called a [Single System Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image) cluster.  There is/was a project called [MOSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSIX) for Linux which did this, but then it went proprietary, then forked into [OpenMosix](http://openmosix.org/), then discontinued by the dev in 2008 (because it wasn't needed due to cheap and readily available multi-core/multi-threaded CPUs), and continued with the [LinuxPMI](https://infogalactic.com/info/LinuxPMI) project

Comment: linuxpmi.org is unavailable right now, I will try other day. Distcc looks promising too, I have to try it, thx!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with any of the mosix derivatives.  at best, they're limited to ancient kernels, 2.6.x.   `distcc` will do what you want - assuming it can be made to work compiling UE.

Comment: I found out that there is support for distcc and fastbuild at https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/BuildConfiguration/